# Seeking logic to scan array for next active time slot

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to define the logic that would return a value of the next live show time per day for a media station.

**The array**

```
$liveshows = [
  'mon' => [
                ['start' => '0600', 'end' => '0900', 'host' => 'Joe'],
                ['start' => '1300', 'end' => '1500', 'host' => 'Carol'],
                ['start' => '1500', 'end' => '1600', 'host' => 'Cortez'],
                ['start' => '1700', 'end' => '2100', 'host' => 'Boy George']
              ],
];
```

**Process**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$day          = strtolower(date('D'));
$current_time = date('Hi');

$html=''; $start=[];
if( $day == 'mon' && !empty( $liveshows['mon'] ) ) 
{
  foreach( $liveshows['mon'] as $showtime ) {
    if( $current_time >= $showtime['start'] && $current_time <= $showtime['end'] )
      $html .= '<h3>' . $showtime['host'] . ' <span>is on air</span></h3>';
      
      // create an array of start times to use in below 'no live show' notice.
      $start[] = $showtime['start'];
  }
}

// print it
echo $html;
```

**All works fine to that point.**

Now I want to **show a notice when there is no live host on air** so I've used `current()`, `next()` and `end()` to cycle the `$start` array. It works to a point but fails because the array `count()` is not consistent per day.

```
if( empty( $html ) ) 
{
  $nextshow='';
  if( $current_time < current($start) ) {
    $nextshow = current($start);
  }
  elseif( $current_time < next($start) ) {
    $nextshow = next($start);
  }

  echo '<h3>No live show is on</h3>';
  echo '<p>The next live show is at ' . date('g:iA', strtotime( $nextshow )) . '</p>';
}
```

The output notice when retrieved is:

From midnight

**The next live show is at 6:00AM**

Between first show and next

**The next live show is at 1:00PM**

After the 1600 (4PM) show end time, the process fails and the output is without the 5PM value for the next in array and just...

**The next live show is**

---

How do I correctly scan the array and compare to current time to check if a show is on, and if not, show the time of the next show in line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's quite cumbersome to use `current/next` in your case. You can simplify your code greatly by keeping track on whether any show is on air `$isOnAir = true/false` (in below code) and if not, simply reiterating the shows array with a different condition.

Example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$day          = strtolower(date('D'));
$current_time = date('Hi');

// test
$day          = 'mon';
$current_time = '1630';

$liveshows = [
    'mon' => [
        ['start' => '0600', 'end' => '0900', 'host' => 'Joe'],
        ['start' => '1300', 'end' => '1500', 'host' => 'Carol'],
        ['start' => '1500', 'end' => '1600', 'host' => 'Cortez'],
        ['start' => '1700', 'end' => '2100', 'host' => 'Boy George'],
    ],
];

if ($day === 'mon' && !empty($liveshows['mon'])) {
    // assume no show is on air
    $isOnAir = false;

    foreach ($liveshows['mon'] as $showtime) {
        if ($showtime['start'] <= $current_time && $current_time <= $showtime['end']) {
            // we have a show on air
            $isOnAir = true;

            // output
            echo '<h3>', $showtime['host'], ' <span>is on air</span></h3>';

            // break loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // without a show on air (see above)
    if (!$isOnAir) {
        echo '<h3>No live show is on</h3>';

        foreach ($liveshows['mon'] as $showtime) {
            // find the first where start > current
            if ($current_time < $showtime['start']) {
                // output
                echo '<p>The next live show is at ', date('g:iA', strtotime($showtime['start'])), '</p>';

                // and break loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZKcjo